# Flutter- TextEditingController listener get called multiple time for textfield

Tags: flutter

TextField controlled **controller.addListener(()** gets called multiple time after pressing the clear button, this will only happen if we are clearing it.

**Snippet:**

```
TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
    TextField field = new TextField(
      controller: controller,
      autofocus: true,

    );
    controller.addListener(() {
      print("Pressed cancel button");
    });
```

**Video** [Link](https://vimeo.com/355161215)

Note: While adding characters in TextField listener method gets called only ones.

Comment: so what did you expect ? addListener only called once, so there are no duplication in API or database?

Comment: @ejabu: You got it.

Comment: I have the same problem with Nexus 6p when used with API level 23, but this problem did not occure with Pixel with API28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that would be a defect on flutter, a possible solution would be to use **onChanged()**

```
TextField field = new TextField(
  autofocus: true,
  onChanged: (String value) {
    print("Pressed clear button");
  },

);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Nexus 6p when used with API level 23 and Pixel with API 25.

but this problem did not occurs with Pixel with API28 and it does not occurs with Nexus6P with API26.

exact code from https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes was used.

Answer (score -1):

#### 1. We need to create our own .clear() method

```dart
void clearField() {
  print("c: clearField");
  var newValue = textController.value.copyWith(
    text: '',
    selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0),
  );
  textController.value = newValue;
  callApi('');
}

// and call it by : 

child: TextField(
  controller: textController,
  autofocus: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    suffixIcon: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.close),
      onPressed: clearField, // call
    ),
  ),
),
```

#### 2. We need to carefully handle changes

```dart
void changesOnField() {
  print("c: changesOnField");
  String text = textController.text;
  if (text.isNotEmpty) { // set this
    callApi(text);
  }
}
```

#### Full Code

You may look into this repo and build it locally [Github](https://github.com/ejabu/flutter_text_field_control/blob/master/lib/c_screen/clear_text.dart)

#### Result

[image]